# Change columns number based on the window size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to change the layout using CSS only, so when windows size < x then I have the text on one column with width of 100% and when window >= x then make it two columns with each width set to 50%?

**For example:**

*one column:*

```
first part of the example text
second part of the example text
```

*two columns:*

```
first part of the                 second part of the
example text                       example text
```

Comment: Do you have Jquery as a tag because you can use scripting?

Answer (score 6):

Try it with media queries - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/q883p/6/)

```css
div {
    border: 1px solid #c00;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 481px) {
    div { 
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
           -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
                box-sizing: border-box;
        float: left;
        width: 50%; 
    }
}​
```

Comment: Using ems is really a much better choice than px:  http://blog.cloudfour.com/the-ems-have-it-proportional-media-queries-ftw/

Comment: @cimmanon that's absolutely correct, but this is just an example since the OP was talking about a width of *"x"* and not real numbers

Comment: I would recommend using `box-sizing:border-box;` and setting width to 50% in this instance.

Comment: Here's the same example updated with text (and ems): http://jsfiddle.net/q883p/4/

Comment: Media queries are certainly the answer in this case, but it would be better to go the other way (from narrow to wide).

Comment: @Ana that depends on OP's visitors - if most of them desktop users (what I was assuming) it's better to go widescreen initially and narrow the stuff for mobiles later if needed..

Comment: I was talking about the fact that it is easier (and more considerate) to create the layout for the less capable mobile browsers first. Why feed the less capable browsers styles that you overwrite anyway afterwards in a media query? One column is the default. So just for the width, you don't need to specify anything for the narrow screen with a mobile first approach. Which means you don't overwrite the width in the media query.

Comment: @Ana you mean the *mobile first* approach? makes sense, agree

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with media queries, which will deliver different stylesheets depending on the screen size.

HTML:

```
<div class="col1">Lorem ipsum  ... interdum mi.</div>
<div class='col2'>Integer varius,  ... sagittis dolor.</div>​
```

CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 500px) {
    .col1, .col2 { width: 45%; float: left}
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FKSkv/1/

Answer (score 0):

At first you can use CSS3 `column-count:` property.
And adding column class  with the help of JavaScript at your special screen width condition.